# Python: Trying to send a 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' Post Request but having Config Errors

Tags: python, post, request, http.client

I have tried every which way to send the below request but I either get a **500 response** (Internal Server Error) when I send the **book_token** in as a string or the below error when I send it in as a dictionary:

`"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1049, in _send_output chunk = f'{len(chunk):X}\r\n'.encode('ascii') + chunk \ TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`

The request **works** in **POSTMAN** (The suggested code does not though) and **BURP SUITE** so I believe that it is a configuration issue in my Python Code but I have no idea where. Any help would be amazing thank you!

**Python Code**

```
# Request: Book Reservation
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.resy.com")

payload = f"book_token={urllib.parse.quote_plus(book_token)}&struct_payment_method={urllib.parse.quote_plus(struct_payment)}&source_id=resy.com-venue-details"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-Resy-Auth-Token': x_resy_token,
    'Authorization': auth_token,
    'X-Resy-Universal-Auth': x_resy_token,
  }
conn.request("POST", "/3/book", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

**Burp Suite Request**

```
POST /3/book HTTP/2
Host: api.resy.com
Content-Length: 871
Sec-Ch-Ua: 
X-Origin: https://widgets.resy.com
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
X-Resy-Auth-Token: <MY_TOKEN>
Authorization: <MY_TOKEN>
User-Agent: <STUFF>
Chrome/115.0.5790.110 Safari/537.36
X-Resy-Universal-Auth: <MY_TOKEN>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: ""
Origin: https://widgets.resy.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://widgets.resy.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

book_token=<TOKEN>&struct_payment_method=<MY_TOKEN>&source_id=resy.com-venue-details
```

**Conclusion**

I have tried using both the requests **package** and **http.client** and organizing the request in every way I can think of but nothing works

Comment: Use the `requests` module. Then you can use `requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)`

Comment: I tried that package, it doesn't work either

Comment: Are you sure the API expects url-encoded parameters not JSON?

Comment: Yes 100 percent sure

Answer (score 0):

Use `requests`. `payload` should then be a dictionary, which will be formatted by `requests.post()`.

```
import requests

payload = {
    'book_token': book_token,
    'struct_payment_method': struct_payment,
    'source_id': resy.com-venue-details
}
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-Resy-Auth-Token': x_resy_token,
    'Authorization': auth_token,
    'X-Resy-Universal-Auth': x_resy_token,
}

res = requests.post('https://api.resy.com/3/book', data=payload, headers=headers)
print(res.text)
```